# reflection - Get enum that is inside a class

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class with a enum in it and a constructor, that is using it as parameter.

```
public class Example {
  public enum ExampleEnum {WORK,IDLE};
  public Example(ExampleEnum e, String s){...}
  // Class body
}
```

But if I get enum value from it and pass it as argument to contstructor, I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`

This is the code that I am using:

```
Object enumVal = Class.forName("Example$ExampleEnum").getField("WORK").get(null);
Object instance = Class.forName("Example").getConstructor(
        enumVal.getClass(),
        String.class).newInstance(
            enumVal,
            "test"
);
```

(The class exists)

Comment: Add package name before `Example$ExampleEnum` and `Example`.

Comment: What are you trying to get? Is it the text `WORK` or the enum constant `WORK`?

Comment: Works fine for me if I add full package name in `forName(..)` like `Class.forName("com.stackoverflow.q37496837.Example$ExampleEnum")` and `Class.forName("com.stackoverflow.q37496837.Example")`.

Comment: The class I used was wierd, because it works with other classes. I used some lib to do it's work.